# rowSelect event doesn't work in browsers on iPad

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Why the rowSelect event doesn't work in iPad?

```
<h:form id="formA">
    <p:spacer width="10" />
    <p:dataTable
        currentPageReportTemplate="Records {startRecord} to {endRecord} from {totalRecords} - Total pages: {totalPages}"
        id="customers" paginator="true"
        paginatorPosition="bottom"
        paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {CurrentPageReport}"
        rowKey="#{customer.id}"
        rows="15"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,20"
        selectionMode="single"
        value="#{customersBB.customers}"
        var="customer">

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{customersBB.selectCustomer}"
            update=":formB" />

        <p:column headerText="id">
            <h:outputText value="#{customer.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="name">
            <h:outputText value="#{customer.name}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <p:dataTable value="#{customer.purchases}" var="purchase">
                <p:columnGroup type="header">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column headerText="product" />
                        <p:column headerText="price" />
                    </p:row>
                </p:columnGroup>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{purchase.productName}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{purchase.price}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

I have not found my problem

Comment: What web browser are you using on the iPad?

Comment: Safari and Chrome. The problem happens in the two browsers